# Twitter-bootstrap navbar div element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

how can I use a div element in the navbar dropdown? Everytime I use a div, the dropdown dont work.

I´ve tried a few methods, always following bootstrap website examples but with no success.

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container"> 
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <i class="icon-bar"></i>
            <i class="icon-bar"></i>
            <i class="icon-bar"></i>
         </a>
             <a class="brand" href="#">Test</a>

        <div class="nav-collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="dropdown"> 
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown<i class="caret"></i></a>

                    <div class="test"><!-- Works without this div -->

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li> <a href="#">Link</a>

                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="#">Link</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li> <a href="#">Link</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div><!-- End the div -->

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here´s a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GGMWX/357/
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is not allowing other elements is this dropdowns. you will have to make your own drop downs if you want to have a div around.

Comment: I just cant find the solution anywhere! But i´m sure adding support for divs is entirely necessary!